# How can I add week days to date?

Tags: javascript, datetime

Will the below code work for adding week days in all possible scenarios?
eg, If I add 4 days to a "Thursday", the result should be next "Wednesday".

I am trying to get the nth working day (weekday) after a given day.

```
var addOneDay=function(date) {
    var result = new Date(date.getTime());
    result.setDate(result.getDate() + 1);
    return result;
};

var addWeekDays = function(date,days) {
    var result = new Date(date.getTime());
    for (var i = 0; i < days; i++) {
        do{
            result = addOneDay(result);
        }while( result.getDay()=== 6 || result.getDay()=== 0);
    };
    return result;
};

var date = new Date(2016,1,18);
console.log(addWeekDays(date,4));
```

Reworked code based on suggestions by ElenaDBA and Felix Kling:

```
var addWeekDays = function(date,days) {
    var result = new Date(date.getTime());
    for (var i = 0; i < days; i++) {
        result.setDate(result.getDate() + 1);
        if (result.getDay()=== 6 || result.getDay()=== 0) i--;
    };
    return result;
};

var date = new Date(2016,1,18);
console.log(addWeekDays(date,4));
```

Comment: The code seems to do what you want. Why don't you write a simple test? That's what unit tests are there for.

Comment: If you add 4 days to a Thursday, you should get next Tuesday

Comment: What exactly you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: It seems to me that if you only want to add weekdays, not the weekends, then you should have while(result.getDay()!==6 && result.getDay() !== 0)

Comment: Actually the code posted does not work the way desired. It returns 2/28/2016, counting only the weekends. So if input is a Wednesday, it returns the next Sunday

Comment: @ElenaDBA: The code posted in the question returns 2/24/2016 for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like that?

```
 var addOneDay = function (date) {
            var result = new Date(date.getTime());
            result.setDate(result.getDate() + 1);
            return result;
        };

        var addWeekDays = function (date, days) {
            var result = new Date(date.getTime());
            var counter = 1;
            while(counter <= days) {
                if (result.getDay() !== 6 && result.getDay() !== 0) {
                    counter = counter +1;
                }
                result = addOneDay(result);                  
            };
            return result;
        };

        var date = new Date(2016, 1, 18);
        console.log(addWeekDays(date, 4));
```

In this case the input date is 2/18/2016 and the output is 2/24/2016, just like you wanted

Comment: What did you change and why? How / why / when is this "better" than the OP's code?

Comment: OP's code adds days when result.getDay returns either 6 or 0, saturday or synday, and what OP is trying to do per question is to only add the weekdays.

Comment: The OP's code adds *additional* days if the day is Saturday or Sunday, which is correct. If you start at Thursday and want to add 4 weekdays, you need to add 4 + 2 = 6 days. You are basically doing the same thing by not increasing `counter` if it's a Saturday or Sunday. Did you actually run the OP's code?

Comment: There is absolutely no need for a double loop. one loop is more then enough. To be honest, I do not even see the need to add days using the addOneDay function. Using result.setDate instead should be just fine

Comment: *"There is absolutely no need for a double loop. one loop is more then enough."* That's true. There multiple ways to implement this logic. But correctness is more important than implementation detail. You claim that the OP's code is incorrect, given a false impression to every other visitor. The OP's code works as far as I can tell.